# Find curve that minimizes lenght, with integral constraint

Tags: calculus-of-variations, boundary-value-problem, euler-lagrange-equation

I'm interested in finding the curve $q(t):[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+$ that satisfies the boundary conditions $q(0)=q(1)=0$, the integral condition $\int_0^1q(t)dt=a>0$, and that minimizes the functional $J(q,\dot{q}, t)=\int_0^1\sqrt{1+\dot{q}^2}dt$, that is the length of the curve $q$ ($\dot{q}$ indicates the first derivative of $q$). Other conditions that might be relevant are: $q \in C^n$ for some $n>2$, $q$ is strictly concave with maximum at $1/2$. Practically, something that looks like a concave parabola, a catenary or a hyperbole.

Applying Hamilton's variational principle without the conditions to this simple functional $J$ obviously returns a linear curve, so I'm looking for a way of including the conditions (especially the integral one) and still apply Hamilton's principle. My first idea was that if $q$ is stationary for $J$, it will be stationary also for $J+\lambda a=\int_0^1\sqrt{1+\dot{q}^2}dt+\lambda\int_0^1  q(t)dt$ for some $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$, so one might instead try the functional $I=\int_0^1\sqrt{1+\dot{q}^2}+\lambda q(t)dt$, with respective Lagrangian $L=\sqrt{1+\dot{q}^2}+\lambda q$. Applying Hamilton's principle to this functional returns the curve $q(t)=\sqrt{1-(\lambda t)^2}-1$, which is not what i'm looking for.

I'm looking for ways of including both the integral and boundary conditions in the application of Hamilton's principle, hopefully by simple playing around with the functional.
The problem arose after looking at a plastic peel covering a bowl with some rising pizza dough. The dough produces gassy volume that expands the peel more or less like a balloon. Thus the gas produced occupies a certain volume (area $a$ in the 2 dimensional case), and we want to minimize the length of the curve of the plastic peel to minimize the amount of stretching required.

Comment: Why $q(t)=\sqrt{1-(\lambda t)^2}-1$ is not what you look for?

Comment: BTW, a "dual" version of this question is the famous [area maximizing function with fixed arc length](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1303963/what-function-maximizes-area-for-a-constant-arc-length). I feel their solution shall be connected

Comment: @BinxuWang王彬旭 because that $q$ can't satisfy $q(1)=0$ (not usefully, at least). Also, I should have precised that I want $q(t)>0\forall t$, although I believe it not necessary to require it as a condition, because the integral condition seems to force it anyway.

Comment: @BinxuWang王彬旭 i've found a mistake in my calculations, using the functional $I$ returns a different curve which can be made to satisfy the constraints, although it seems to admit a maximum area of $a=\pi/8$. I imagined there would have been no limit to $a$... Tomorrow I'll write an answer I guess...

Comment: Exactly, $a=\pi/8$ is the extreme case where the $q(x)$ form a half circle. Larger than that the case is described in the post above [ area maximizing function with fixed arc length](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1303963/what-function-maximizes-area-for-a-constant-arc-length)  they have a similar problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are almost all correct, except for one step which you missed an arbitrary integration constant.

After applying the Euler Lagrange equation
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\dot q}{\sqrt{1+\dot q^2}} = \lambda
$$
Here you miss a constant term when integrating $t$
$$
\frac{\dot q}{\sqrt{1+\dot q^2}} = \lambda t+c\\
\dot q^2=\frac{(\lambda t+c)^2}{1-(\lambda t+c)^2}\\
\dot q=\pm\sqrt\frac{(\lambda t+c)^2}{1-(\lambda t+c)^2}
$$
Doing indefinite integration of $q$ gets
$$
q(t)=\pm\frac{1}{\lambda}\sqrt{1-(\lambda t+c)^2} +K
$$
We can pick the $+$ solution using the boundary condition $q(0)=q(1)=0$, by symmetry we can see
$$
c^2=(\lambda+c)^2\\
c=-\frac{\lambda}{2}
$$
Thus
$$
q(t)=\frac{1}{\lambda}\sqrt{1-\lambda^2 (t-\frac12)^2} -\frac{1}{\lambda}\sqrt{1- \frac{\lambda^2}{4}}
$$
This is an equation for an arc of a circle.
$$
(q(t)-K)^2 + (t-\frac 12)^2=\frac{1}\lambda^2{}
$$